# How to disable the comments Section on annotation on PDFTron Webviewer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, electron, pdftron

I need to disable the comments and replies on annotatation on Doc.
I am using pdftron webviewer version 7. There is way to disable elements like panels... doing `instance.disableElements(['nameOfElement']);` but I do not know how to disable comments. Can sameone help please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `instance.disableReplyForAnnotations` API.

```js
// Disable for every annotation
instance.disableReplyForAnnotations((annot) => true)
```

https://www.pdftron.com/api/web/7.3/WebViewerInstance.html#disableReplyForAnnotations__anchor

Comment: Thanks for replying. This disables alle replies on comments but not the first comment. Is there away to disable the fisrt comment ?